# Multi- part identifier "" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server-2008

I hope you can help fairly new to SQL Server so pleaes be patient.  I'm trying to set a variable from a CASE statement but hitting the mulit-identifier error.  the code is trying to parse a value into a variable depending on date variables being within the date ranges of two date fields.

```
use KSSDB

declare @DateFrom   as datetime,
    @DateTo     as datetime,
    @ResInt     as int,
    @ProgID     as int,
    @PERSID     as int


set @DateFrom = '2010/11/01'
set @DateTo = '2013/11/01'
set @ProgID = 63
set @PERSID = 4492

--select PT.PROG_ID, 
--      PT.PERS_ID, 
--      P.PROG_NAME,
--      format(PT.PROG_TRAI_SD, 'dd/MM/yyyy') as PROG_TRAI_SD, 
--      format(PT.PROG_TRAI_ED, 'dd/MM/yyyy')as PROG_TRAI_ED,

set @resint =   CASE when (@DateFrom > PT.PROG_TRAI_SD and @dateto < PT.PROG_TRAI_ED) then 1
    when (@datefrom > PT.PROG_TRAI_ED and @DateTo > PT.PROG_TRAI_ED) then 2 
    when (@datefrom < PT.PROG_TRAI_SD and @DateTo > PT.PROG_TRAI_ED) then 3 
    else  0
    end

select @ResInt

from    PROG p
    JOIN PROG_TRAI PT ON P.PROG_ID = PT.PROG_ID

where   PT.PROG_ID = @ProgID and 
    PT.PERS_ID = @PERSID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `CASE` statement is separate from your `SELECT ... FROM` and you are attempting to set the `@resint` using data in the table.

Try using something like this:

```
select @resint 
  = CASE when (@DateFrom > PT.PROG_TRAI_SD and @dateto < PT.PROG_TRAI_ED) then 1
         when (@datefrom > PT.PROG_TRAI_ED and @DateTo > PT.PROG_TRAI_ED) then 2 
         when (@datefrom < PT.PROG_TRAI_SD and @DateTo > PT.PROG_TRAI_ED) then 3 
         else  0
    end
from PROG p
JOIN PROG_TRAI PT 
  ON P.PROG_ID = PT.PROG_ID
where PT.PROG_ID = @ProgID and 
    PT.PERS_ID = @PERSID
```

Comment: perfect thanks so much for the quick response sorry to be such a dork